# Consolidate rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, aggregate-functions

Here is my data:

```
ID      FName   LName   data1   data2
1       John    Doe     xxx1    
2       John    Doe     xxx2    yyy2
```

And here is my desired result:

```
ID      FName   LName   data1   data2
1       John    Doe     xxx1    yyy2
```

In short, I have a table where are a lot of people, and that table is filled from multiple sources with different data and IDs.  What I want is, for each duplicate I found and for each column in the table view  if there is data present in that cell, then, if it exists, try to dump it to the oldest record for that person, if there is data, do nothing.

I don't know if I made myself clear.

What should be the best approach to do this? Should I write a stored procedure or it can be done with a clever query I haven't came up with yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with a query using joins and [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select nodups.id, nodups.fname, nodups.lname, d1.data1, d2.data2
from
  (select min(id) as id, fname, lname from sample group by fname, lname) nodups
left join
  (select fname, lname, min(data1) as data1
   from (select fname, lname
           , first_value(data1) over (partition by fname, lname order by id) as data1
         from sample where data1 is not null) d1x
   group by fname, lname
  ) d1 using (fname, lname)
left join
  (select fname, lname, min(data2) as data2
   from (select fname, lname
           , first_value(data2) over (partition by fname, lname order by id) as data2
         from sample where data2 is not null) d2x
   group by fname, lname
  ) d2 using (fname, lname)
order by id
;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5bb12/10)

Try testing this approach with your real data against Igor's custom aggregate to see which performs better.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom aggregate like that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION remember_first(acc text, newval text) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN COALESCE(acc, newval);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE AGGREGATE first(text) (
    sfunc = remember_first,
    stype = text
);
```

It will return the first not `null` value. Then:

```
SELECT FName, LName, first(data1), first(data2)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY FName, LName
ORDER BY FName, LName, id -- or your ordering columns
```

To get the data you need. Last - just use this `SELECT` to update the records. Or just create a `VIEW` with desired data.

P.S. The aggregate function is from [Custom aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350437/postgres-custom-aggregate-function)